# Email not sending with django 1.9

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I've been trying to get email working with a project I've been working on, I believe it's configured correctly, here my settings.py, the command I'm running, and the traceback I get when I stop it.

Email Configuration:

```
    #Email Configuration
    DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = #Email Address
    SERVER_EMAIL = #Email Address
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
    EMAIL_PORT = 587
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = #Email Address
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "**********"
```

Command:

```
    send_mail("Test", "Test", "from_email@gmail.com", ["to_email@gmail.com"], fail_silently=False)
```

Traceback:

```
    ^CTraceback (most recent call last):
      File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/django/DjangoApps/ConnectedFeedback/Py3_ENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 61, in send_mail
        return mail.send()
      File "/home/django/DjangoApps/ConnectedFeedback/Py3_ENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 292, in send
        return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
      File "/home/django/DjangoApps/ConnectedFeedback/Py3_ENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
        new_conn_created = self.open()
      File  "/home/django/DjangoApps/ConnectedFeedback/Py3_ENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 58, in open
        self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port,     **connection_params)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 242, in __init__
        (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 321, in connect
        self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 292, in _get_socket
        self.source_address)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 503, in create_connection
        sock.connect(sa)
    KeyboardInterrupt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I ran `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` and it sat there for like 5 minutes but eventually connected

Comment: Why are you stopping it?

Comment: Working from another email client?

Comment: Looks like a timeout. Can you telnet to smtp.gmail.com:587 from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it ended up just being an issue with google account security. Google was blocking the sign in attempt.